# C++ Checking for identical values in 2 arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I have 2 arrays called `xVal`, and `yVal`.

I'm using these arrays as coords. What I want to do is to make sure that the array doesn't contain 2 identical sets of coords.

Lets say my arrays looks like this:

```
int xVal[4] = {1,1,3,4};
int yVal[4] = {1,1,5,4};
```

Here I want to find the match between `xVal[0]` `yVal[0]` and `xVal[1]` `yVal[1]` as 2 identical sets of coords called 1,1.

I have tried some different things with a forLoop, but I cant make it work as intended.

Comment: It will be much easier to do if you have just one array of coords, perhaps modeled as `std::pair<int, int>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with two for loops:

```
int MAX=4; //number of elements in array
for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
{
    for (int j=i+1; j<MAX; j++)
    {
        if (xVal[i]==xVal[j] && yVal[i]==yVal[j])
        {
            //DUPLICATE ELEMENT at xVal[j], yVal[j]. Here you implement what
            //you want (maybe just set them to -1, or delete them and move everything
            //one position back)
        }
    }
}
```

Small explanation: first variable i get value 0. Than you loop j over all possible numbers. That way you compare xVal[0] and yVal[0] with all other values. j starts at i+1 because you don't need to compare values before i (they have already been compared).

Edit - you should consider writing small class that will represent a point, or at least structure, and using std::vector instead of arrays (it's easier to delete an element in the middle). That should make your life easier :)

Comment: This is a really bad approach in general because it is O(n²).

Answer (score 2):

You can write an explicit loop using an O(n^2) approach (see answer from x77aBs) or you can trade in some memory for performance. For example using `std::set`

```
bool unique(std::vector<int>& x, std::vector<int>& y)
{
    std::set< std::pair<int, int> > seen;
    for (int i=0,n=x.size(); i<n; i++)
    {
        if (seen.insert(std::make_pair(x[i], y[i])).second == false)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int identicalValueNum = 0;
int identicalIndices[4]; // 4 is the max. possible number of identical values
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (xVal[i] == yVal[i])
    {
        identicalIndices[identicalValueNum++] = i;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < identicalValueNum; i++)
{
    printf(
        "The %ith value in both arrays is the same and is: %i.\n",
        identicalIndices[i], xVal[i]);
}
```

For

```
int xVal[4] = {1,1,3,4};
int yVal[4] = {1,1,5,4};
```

the output of `printf` would be:

> The 0th value in both arrays is the same and is: 1.
>
> The 1th value in both arrays is the same and is: 1.
>
> The 3th value in both arrays is the same and is: 4.

Comment: S/He's trying to solve a different problem; given a list of 2d points s/he wants to know if all points are distinct or not. The problem in the example is not that the point is `(1, 1)` (i.e. that `x == y`) but that is stored **twice** in the list.